# Optimise CSS Delivery in Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, pagespeed

When using page speed insights I get this alert

```
Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
Your page has 1 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering      your page.
Approximately 3% of the above-the-fold content on your page could be    rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or   asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those   resources directly in the HTML.
Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:
http://www.mysite.co.uk/wp-content/themes/mytheme/css/m.min.css
```

Note: removed the url as it is a working site for my workplace.

I have tried doing what is suggested by google and using

```
<script>
  var cb = function() {
    var l = document.createElement('link'); l.rel = 'stylesheet';
    l.href = 'small.css';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]; h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
  };
  var raf = requestAnimationFrame || mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      webkitRequestAnimationFrame || msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(cb);
  else window.addEventListener('load', cb);
</script>
```

But this did not solve the problem. I have tried removing the css link but it told me to remove the js files and font awesome files as well.

I am currently at 97/100 on page speed insights so I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Is that 3% really worth the fight? I mean. 97% is already pretty good. Loading the css after the html might work but it might result in an ugly loading (load the site without css - default browser styles - and then swap to a styled one. The users will notice that ugly jump)

Comment: @JonasGrumann yeah you're right, I was just hoping that someone may have already addressed the issue and may have had a quick fix for it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to eliminate render blocking CSS is to extract just the "above the fold"  or "critical" CSS that is required to render the page and then inline it into your HTML. From there you can then asynchronously load the remaining CSS required to load the rest of the page.

The idea behind this is that you get all of the resources that you need in one roundtrip to the server with the HTML page. For any remaining or "non-critical" resources, you then load asynchronously. For more details, see [this article](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/OptimizeCSSDelivery) on the Google Developers website.

I find that the best tool to use to extract the Critical CSS is actually a [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com) plugin called [grunt-critical.](https://github.com/bezoerb/grunt-critical) If you've never used Grunt before with Wordpress, there is a [great tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-grunt-with-wordpress-development--cms-21743) on the tuts+ site that will walk you through it.

Apart from that, you can asynchronously load your JavaScript using the [HTML async attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_async.asp).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by including the css required for the hero image inline in the  of the document.

By doing this, the page is not waiting to be able to load the large image.